Background Start Not Allowed for IntentService on Redmi Devices
I'm encountering an issue with starting an IntentService from one application to another on a Redmi device. The problem occurs only on Redmi devices and is related to background restrictions.
Description:
I'm using IntentService, Handler, and Messenger for communication between two applications. When the target application is in a closed state, I attempt to trigger the IntentService and receive the following log message:
Background start not allowed: service Intent { cmp=com.example.project/.nonui.services.UploadDataService (has extras) } to com.example.project/.nonui.services.UploadDataService from pid=9276 uid=10620 pkg=com.example.project startFg?=true
This issue is specific to Redmi devices; the service works as expected on other devices.
Details:

The IntentService is declared in the Android manifest.

I am using min SDK version 26 and target SDK version 30.

I am using a Foreground Service for handling intents.

Background restrictions might be affecting the service on Redmi devices.


Additional Information:

I have tried enabling the background autostart setting for the apps, but the issue persists when triggering the IntentService for the first time while the app is in a closed state.

I've checked the device settings for battery optimization but haven't found a resolution.

I am aware that Redmi devices might have additional background limitations or optimizations.


Questions:

How can I resolve the "Background start not allowed" issue on Redmi devices?

Are there any specific considerations for background services on Xiaomi devices with MIUI?

What steps can I take to ensure that the IntentService is triggered correctly even when the app is closed?


